# Why/When should I declare the methods outside of my class using the scope operator in c++?

Tags: c++

I come from a .Net background and I'm starting to learn c++ I saw in a tutorial [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes/) that it's possible to define the content of a function outside of the class via the scope operator `::`.

Here is the example given in the tutorial:

```
// classes example
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class CRectangle {
    int x, y;
  public:
    void set_values (int,int);
   int area () {return (x*y);}
};

void CRectangle::set_values (int a, int b) {
  x = a;
  y = b;
}

int main () {
  CRectangle rect;
  rect.set_values (3,4);
  cout << "area: " << rect.area();
  return 0;
}
```

All I can find on Google is about scope resolution, but I would like to know why/when should I use the declaration like `set_values` instead of the declaration inside of the class like `area`. Is there any advantages, rules, best practices?

Comment: Read up about header files.

Comment: Normally the class declaration goes into a header file; while you can, in theory put everything in the header, you normally provide implementation in an accompanying .cpp file so it's compiled once and referenced from everywhere else.

Comment: My general rule is that if the method fits on one line then I define it inside the class definition in the header file, otherwise I define it outside of the class definition in a cpp file using the scope operator. But I don't think it's a big deal, just a matter of taste really. These days compilers/linkers are smart enough to inline functions even when they are not defined inline.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd do that only if you want to put the function implementation inside a separate file - mostly .cpp

Header files almost always have a .h extension. The purpose of a header file is to hold declarations for other files to use. You would mostly define here, what the class would look like - the definition of the functions. Useful if you have to do a lot of classes. 
Use the .cpp to go into the details - to actually implement the functions that were "defined" in header file.

If there are a lot of classes involved, using header and cpp files will reduce your build times. If you are feeling very brave and want to reduce your build times even further then I suggest reading up about PIMPL pattern.

You can read up more about the basic information [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/10627/)

Comment: So if I try to reformulate just to see if I understand correctly. The header file with the extension .h contains the contract of the class while the cpp file contains his behavior?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. If you are not going to use a lot of files, it is okay to put the stuff in a single file - the drawback is readability and compilation times.

Answer (score 1):

The main advantage of splitting declaration and implementation comes when you are making code, that will be distributed to end user, e.g. library.

When you hand out the code, you hand out just the header file and object file *.o. That way your super fancy, secret code is safe, compiled inside the .o file, and the end user can still use it, because he has the .h file, co linker knows where to look.

Comment: Often use for SDK or UI controls libraries I suppose?

Comment: Yes, that's an example. In case of SDKs an UI libs you are ussually handed final product - static or dynamic library. But the idea is same. In .Net the DLLs work a bit differently, so you don't need .h file, `using` statement is enough.

Answer (score 1):

It is indeed a good question, and it all boils down to compilation times. People coming from .NET background have some difficulties understanding the difference between `#include` and eg. C#'s `using` statement. What to keep in mind is:

**The `#include` directive copy-pastes the contents of the included file.**

Thus, if you put implementation code in your header, you are essentially compiling it multiple times, once at each `#include` site (and the linker will have to remove the duplicate code). Also, if you change a cpp file, it gets recompiled alone. If you change a header file, all the files including it (also indirectly !) will get recompiled.

So **put as much as possible inside implementation (ie. cpp) files**. Compilers have become good enough as link time code optimization that the fact that this can prevent inlining is less a problem as it was before.

It is not possible with templates though, and this accounts for much of the very long compilation times you can see when using C++.

Answer (score 0):

The point on this is to separate class methods definition, declaration and implementation. This extremely useful if you want to put them in different files (usually, header contains the class definition and the .cpp the class implementation), or even choose for consistency or other reasons not to have everything directly in class body.